# updating values in a table my multiplying values with percentages based on conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables structured as follows:

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."ZILM_SM30_BT_ALL" 
("BT" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"CHANNEL" VARCHAR2(12 BYTE), 
"PARENT" VARCHAR2(12 BYTE), 
"VD" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
"CURRENCY" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
"AMT" NUMBER(18,2), 
"FXSWAP" NUMBER(18,2), 
"STR_REPO" NUMBER(18,2), 
"REPORTING_DAY" DATE);
```

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZcQO.jpg)

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."ZILM_SM30_BT_RF" 
("BT" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"RF" NUMBER(5,4) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"RATIONALE" VARCHAR2(80 CHAR));
```

[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVkfz.jpg)

I need to update column `STR_REPO` in table 1 with the result of the corresponding value in AMT in table 1 multiplied by the value in RF in table 2. The RF value in table 2 to be used as a factor is the one from the entry with the same BT value as in table 1.  (EG: for row 1 in table 1: `STR_REPO`= 162500000* 0.3333 -->(lookup of value in RF column of table 2 for entry with `BT="REP"`)

What I currently have is:

```
UPDATE ZILM_SM30_BT_ALL 
SET STR_REPO = (SELECT a.AMT * b.RF
FROM ZILM_SM30_BT_ALL a INNER JOIN ZILM_SM30_BT_RF b
ON a.BT = b.BT)
```

The error message I get is :

```
UPDATE ZILM_SM30_BT_ALL 
SET STR_REPO = (SELECT a.AMT * b.RF
FROM ZILM_SM30_BT_ALL a INNER JOIN ZILM_SM30_BT_RF b
ON a.BT = b.BT)
```

> Error report: SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more
>   than one row
>   01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the error message, your inner query return more than one row, which is not valid for an update statement.

You need to use a correlated query, the values of the target table are available for use:

```
UPDATE ZILM_SM30_BT_ALL a
SET a.STR_REPO = a.AMT * (SELECT b.RF
                          FROM ZILM_SM30_BT_RF b
                          WHERE a.BT = b.BT)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your help is much appreciated!